# Change Virtual Network Interface of a snapshot

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, network-interface

I had a CentOS 7 Virtual platform setup on a tower computer. I used this for some time and made many VMs with many snapshots that I need. I moved this computer's HDD to a more powerful system, CentOS boots fine however I cannot apply any of the snapshots to any of the VMs because the network interface name that the snapshot used is no longer present.

The snapshots used the interface named enp0s25 but the new tower's interface is named em1.

Virtual Machine Manager throws these errors when I try to apply any snapshot.

```
Error running snapshot 'Fedora24Updated': Unable to get index for interface enp0s25: No such device

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 90, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 126, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/libvirtobject.py", line 83, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/domain.py", line 1134, in revert_to_snapshot
    self._backend.revertToSnapshot(snap.get_backend())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 2070, in revertToSnapshot
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainRevertToSnapshot() failed', dom=self)
libvirtError: Unable to get index for interface enp0s25: No such device
```

My question is: how to save these snapshots, to use the new em1 interface so they can work?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by renaming the interface to the old interface name.
I followed steps found here:
[change network interface name centos7](http://ask.xmodulo.com/change-network-interface-name-centos7.html)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that I also tried on another system with the same problem is to modify the snapshot's xml file directly. I had to modify the interface name and the MAC address for several snapshots.

If the snapshot's name is "Fedora24Updated" you can search for the xml file like this to find it:

```
find / | grep Fedora24Updated
```

Mine happened to be inside of

```
/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/snapshot/DevBox/Fedora24Updated.xml
```

Where "DevBox" is the name of the virtual machine, and Fedora24Updated is the name of the snapshot. I was able to edit the interface and MAC address areas in this xml file directly to solve the problem as well.